# How to create n subplots (box plots) automatically?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to show `n` (e.g. 5) box plots. How can I do it?

df =

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5  result
1    3    1    1    4     0
1    2    2    4    9     1
1    2    1    3    7     1
```

This is my current code. But it does not display the data inside plots. Also, plots are very thin if `n` is for example 10 (is it possible to go to a new line automatically?).

```
n=5
columns = df.columns

i = 0
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, n, figsize=(20,5))
for ax in axes:
  df.boxplot(by="result", column = [columns[i]], vert=False, grid=True)
  i = i + 1
display(fig)
```

This example is for Azure Databricks, but I appreciate just a matplotlib solution as well if it's applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got what you are trying to do, but the following code will show you the plots. You can control the figure sizes by changing the values of (10,10)

**Code:**

```
df.boxplot(by="result",figsize=(10,10));
```

**Result:**

[image]

To change the Vert and show the grid :

```
df.boxplot(by="result",figsize=(10,10),vert=False, grid=True);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself as follows:

```
df.boxplot(by="result", column = columns[0:4], vert=False, grid=True, figsize=(30,10), layout = (3, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want additional row to be generated, while fixing the number of columns to be constant: adjust the layout as follows:

```
In [41]: ncol = 2

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
   v0  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0   0   3   6   9  12  15  18
1   1   4   7  10  13  16  19
2   2   5   8  11  14  17  20

In [43]: df.boxplot(by='v6', layout=(df.shape[1] // ncol + 1, ncol))  # use floor division to determine how many row are required
```

[image]